# Place a Whitespace before a sign (!?)

Tags: java, regex, replace

I did a little program which add a whitespace before those signs ! ?. I use a regex form but I think my regex doesn't work.
My code

```
try {
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    BufferedWriter out1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath +".txt"));

    try {
        String line;
        String Newligne =System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
        while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.length() !=0) {
                /*if (line.substring(line.length()-1, line.length()).equals("!") || line.substring(line.length()-1, line.length()).equals("?")){
                    line = line.substring(0,line.length()-1) + " " + line.substring(line.length()-1, line.length());
                }*/
                line.replaceAll("(.)([!])", "$1 $2");
                out1.write(line + Newligne);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        out1.close();
        buff.close();
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Erreur --" + ioe.toString());
}
```

If someone can explain me how to do my regex correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) so

```
line.replaceAll("(.)([!])", "$1 $2");
```

will not change original value of `line` String, but will return new String with replaced characters. If you want to replace value in `line` with result of `replaceAll` use

```
line = line.replaceAll("(.)([!])", "$1 $2");
```

Also if you want to add space before any of `!` `?` then you should also include `?` in your regex so try maybe with

```
line = line.replaceAll("([!?])", " $1");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really are just trying to find all the `!` or `?`, then just do a while loop with an inner `string.indexOf(...)` check.  Then as you find each index, append the substring from the last position to just before the character into a `StringBuilder`.

Regex is a powerful tool, but in this case it doesn't buy you much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookahead if you want to add space before `!` or `?`,

```
line = line.replaceAll("(?=[?!])", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line=line.replaceAll("(.)([!])", "$1 $2");
```

Comment: I used to make that mistake all the time hehe.